# Copy all checked list item to another list

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I trying to realize some features.
When I checked item, it copy to second list.
All work.
I add button, which sets all checkbox as checked.
But when I click it, all items dont copy to second list.
Can you help me?

```
<p>First List</p>
<ul class='first-list'>
  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' id='ckbx1'><label for='ckbx1'>One</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' id='ckbx2'><label for='ckbx2'>Two</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' id='ckbx3'><label for='ckbx3'>Tree</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='checkbox' id='ckbx4'><label for='ckbx4'>Four</label>
  </li>
</ul>
 <span class="addAll">Add All</span>
<p>Second List</p>
<ul class='second-list'>
</ul>
```

And Jquery

```
var $chk = $('.first-list input').change(function() {
  $('.second-list').html(
    $chk.filter(':checked').map(function() {
      return $(this).parent().clone();
    }).get()
  );
})
$('.addall').click(function() {
    $('.first-list input').prop('checked',true);
})
```

Here is fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/gf4xm8pk/3/

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to trigger the change event:

```
$('.addall').click(function() {
    $('.first-list input').prop('checked',true).trigger('change');
})
```

An [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gf4xm8pk/5/).

The change event occurs when there is user interaction: a click or keyboard event, for example. When you programmatically affect the state or value of an item, the events attached don't generally automatically fire, so you have to force it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

My solution may be long but Its *All your code*.
So try `fiddle`